# User defined distortion in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, distort

I have a text with different letters.

I would like to distort the the typefaces of these letters in Adobe Illustrator. I know there are a lot of possibilities for this, but I would like to use the same distort feature for different typefaces (shapes).

Of course first I've made outline from the typefaces so actually they are shapes. The shapes have different boundary boxes depends on how big was a typeface, but I want to transform all these shapes each by each for example an oval shape with the original letter (shape) content with the exactly same distort feature.

Let's say I wanna use the same distortion for the shapes. I mean to use the same distortion arcs for example on the upper and the lower part of the shapes.

Can I make a user defined distortion in Illustrator and copy and apply all of them for each shape (letter or typeface)?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Have you explored `Object > Envelope Distort`, Graphic Styles, Type on a path?

Comment: Ok, maybe I was too complicated. I have letters with normal forms. I wanna distort them for example to oval form or a triangle form, all of them separetly not the whole text. Can I save the Envelope Distort form and use again and again for the letters?

Comment: @Franky Applying it is nondestructive. So just copying it and changing the text accomplishes this.

Answer (score 2):

Select your text and apply the envelope warp.

When you select the new text and hit the **make envelope** icon, you will get the same values. Just hit **OK**.

See the imagem below.

One more thing:

If you have an old file...

Select the warped text, go to Menu **Object>>Envelop distort>>Reset with warp** and hit OK.

Now your settings are stored to be applyed to a new text object.

[image]

EDIT: After applying the warp you can freely adjust the envelope to change the distortion:
[image: Enevelope Distoriton]

You can then duplicate that. Go to object -> envelope distort -> release. Grab that top object, put it on some other text and hit object –> envelope distort -> make with top object.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!! I wanted more or less exactly that. But for the Warp Options there are only predefined shapes, for example I can't save a modified arc and use that envelope again, because the data always set back to the original arc settings.

Comment: Read the text again, after: **If you have an old file...** @Franky